Wso2 - Enterprise integrator - Error after doing a json call just after a url encoded payload
I have a sequence where i start by doing a url encoded REST call followed by a json api rest call as follows:
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format>
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <soapenv:Body>
                <root>
                    <grant_type>client_credentials</grant_type>
                </root>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
    </format>
    <args/>
</payloadFactory>
<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>
<property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>

[ call mediator etc.]
then json api call:
  <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>
                            $1
            </format>
            <args>
                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('REQUEST')"  xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
                     </args>
        </payloadFactory>

Once the third party receives this call, it throws an error when parsing the list of objects present under this payload:
JSON parse error: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31)): only regular white space (\r, \n, \t) is allowed between tokens; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31)): only regular white space (\r, \n, \t) is allowed between tokens\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream);
To note that if i skip the first url encoded call, i dont get any errors. I tried to change message type to application/json just before doing the second call but it did not solve the issue, i even tried to re-set the content-type, accept and accept-encoding headers but also it did not solve the issue.
Please i need help.

Solved by adding   before the second call.
